# kql Query to get number of TriggersStarted per hour from last 7 days

Tags: azure, kql

I tried following query  to get number of TriggersStarted per hour from last 7 days (24 hour * 7 day == 168 hour values for TriggerStarted values)
[image]
I tried using the following query

```
 AzureMetrics
| where TimeGenerated between ( ago(7d) .. endofday(ago(1d)) )
| where MetricName == "TriggersStarted"
| summarize count() by Hour=datetime_part("Hour", TimeGenerated)
| summarize bn = min(count_)
```

i tweaked in some changes add tried different functions like bin and range functions but i didnt got accurate results. If anyone knows a good approach to get better results please  guide me with some kind of examples or by suggesting some functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are looking for something like this:

```
AzureMetrics
| where TimeGenerated between (startofday(ago(7d)) .. endofday(ago(1d)))
| where MetricName == "TriggersStarted"
| summarize count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h)
| order by TimeGenerated asc
```

Comment: AzureMetrics
| where TimeGenerated between ( ago(7d) .. endofday(ago(1d)) )
| where MetricName == "TriggersStarted"
| summarize LastWeek=count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h) 
//| sort by TimeGenerated desc 
| summarize  min_triigers = min(LastWeek) 
| join
(
    AzureMetrics
    | where TimeGenerated > now() - 1h
    | where MetricName == "TriggersStarted"
    | summarize Today_SoFar=count() 
) on min_triggers

Comment: I tried above query to compare min number of TriggersStarted (from 1 hour bucket) from past 1 week to TriggersStarted from last 1 hour today.But i am failing to join the columns as i dont have common column to merge the both tables. is there anyway i can improve query to get that result?

Comment: Please follow SO guidelines. Each post should be around a single issue. Since this answer seems to solve your original issue, accept it, upvote if you like, and post a new question for your current issue.